# Get particluar values from a string in PHP

Tags: php

My string is :

```
$mystring = "https://maps.google.com/?ll=37.0625,-95.677068&spn=37.188995,86.572266&t=m&z=4";
```

Now I want those values which I have marked as bold from the string. How can I achieve this with PHP?

Comment: Dear pramod i am not talking about getting a query string from a URL. I want those values from that "String". It is not actually a URL. Consider it as a just a string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [preg\_match url get parameter parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530361/preg-match-url-get-parameter-parsing)

Comment: have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 3):

Use the following functions [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php). You could do something like this the following

```
$url = "https://maps.google.com/?ll=**37.0625,-95.677068**&spn=**37.188995,86.572266**&t=m&z=4";
$parts = parse_url($url);

if(isset($parts['query'])) {
    parse_str(urldecode($parts['query']), $result);
    print_r($result)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)  or [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) or [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to use $_GET['ll'] and $_GET['spn'] to repectively obtain 37.0625,-95.677068 and 37.188995,86.572266

Comment: Guys i am not talking about getting a query string from a URL. I want those values from that "String". It is not actually a URL. Consider it as a just a string.

Answer (score 0):

Here regular expression will be most efficient to parse your required values.

```
$url = "https://maps.google.com/?ll=37.0625,-95.677068&spn=37.188995,86.572266&t=m&z=4";
$regex = "/[-]*\d+.\d*/";

preg_match_all($regex,$url,$out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
// $out = array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(7) "37.0625" [1]=> string(10) "-95.677068" [2]=> string(9) "37.188995" [3]=> string(9) "86.572266" } }
```